# Still getting useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. I am using Remix

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, remix, remix.run, testing-library

I am trying to pass this test but I keep getting this error from Jest even when I wrap the component with a  or  component.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Accordion from '../Accordion'

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

describe('Accordion component', () => {
    const props = {
       title: 'Test Title',
       subtitle: 'Test Subtitle',
       svg: '/test.svg',
       className: 'test-class',
       id: 'test-accordion',
       completed: true,
    }
}


it('renders accordion title and subtitle', () => {
    render(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Accordion {...props}>Content</Accordion>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
    expect(screen.getByText('Test Title')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText('Test Subtitle')).toBeInTheDocument()
})})
```

Here is my error from Jest:

FAIL  app/components/Accordion/**tests**/Accordion.test.tsx
Accordion component
✕ renders accordion title and subtitle (189 ms)

● Accordion component › renders accordion title and subtitle

```
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

  17 | }: AccordionProps) => {
  18 |     const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
> 19 |     const { pathname } = useLocation()
     |                                     ^
  20 |
  21 |     useEffect(() => {
  22 |         const isOpenInStorage = localStorage.getItem('isOpen')
```